# Why does STS deploy a WAR file in every time I edit a .css file in a Grails project?

Tags: java, web-applications, grails, spring-mvc

I am new at Grails development and am finding that when I am using STS (Spring Tool Suite) and editing various files in a Grails project, some files will cause the WAR file to be rebuilt and redeployed, and some will let me simply refresh the browser to see my changes (.gsp file for example).

The real problem is when I am working on a .css file. Whenever I make a change and save, the STS IDE automatically rebuilds the WAR file and redeploys it to the server which is time consuming when I am messing with a layout. Is there some configuration I can do to edit these files and not have to rebuild and redeploy the WAR file?

Comment: you can de-select the option "Build Automatically" if you want STS not to build automatically.

Comment: If I de-select "build automatically" and edit and save a .css file, the project still seems to build and deploy the WAR file to the server.

Comment: STS/Eclipse focused java primaryly. To code Groovy you better use intellij.

Comment: @PeterRader: Fail. STS is designed to use grails & groovy, if you have the proper plugins installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the grails console to start the server: CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+G, enter "run-app". In this mode, you have a server running, which is able to do all kind of hot-deployments for css, javascript, images, GSPs, controllers, services, taglibs, configurations, I18n and so on.

Changes to the domain-model will mostly require require a restart of the server. Anything else can be tested immediately.

Comment: unless I am doing something else wrong, when I use the grails command deploy-app, it will run the app on the server, but if I then edit a css file when it is running, the IDE will automagically run that command again and I will have to wait for the WAR to get built and deployed.

Comment: Don't deploy manually.. Use the Run-App Command. It will startup a Server by itself. You do Not Need to Care about deploying and packaging in dev Mode.

Answer (score 0):

after the latest sts update, i also recognize some strange behaviour. i normally start the app with 'run-app', while the app is running and i edit some files, sts fires automatically a 'dev war' command in a new console window.

i have no option found to disable this. anyone else can confirm this?

Comment: i found the mistake. i used sts tc server with spring inSight, so the app was also connected with the tc-server, which started the 'dev war' command.

Answer (score 0):

@raoulinksi

You need to ensure that your project is not deployed to the internal STS Tomcat Server.  This can be done in the Server view in STS.  If that view is not shown, go to Window->Show View->Servers.

In the Servers view, expand the SpringSource tc Server Developer Edition, right click your project and select Remove.  This will stop the constant rebuilding of the war file.

Note: Even if the internal STS Tomcat Server is stopped, you still need to remove your project from the server list as it will still be rebuilt with any minor change.

HTH